# What is the data I need to send in the ASP.NET Web API project /token request?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, oauth

In Visual Studio 2013 I created a default ASP.NET Web API project. I changed nothing in the code. I created a default user with the /Register request. It works, I have a user in my membership database.

I'm now trying to get a token. I use REST Client, the Firefox add-on. Here is my request and the error:

[image]

I tryed with ", without " around password. What is wrong?

--- EDIT ---

If I remove Accept and Accept-Encoding I the request is called. My break point on ValidateClientAuthentication is called.
But I get another message: "error": "unsupported_grant_type"

Comment: content-type maybe application/json?

Comment: same issue with content-type application/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- The content-type must url encoded.

2- Since it is url encoded, you need to encode the request body, so it should be

```
grant_type=password&username=yourusername&password=theuserpassword
```

so you don't need to pass the request body as an object {},

Refer to this tutorial about Web API 2 with Individual user account

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api